# Generate any number of Views

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

I want to generate multiple `TextView`s based on how many semicolons the users enters between inputs in an `EditText`. 
And it works so far, the only problem is that all `TextView`s are on top of each other, so I need to have the second `TextView` be positioned below the first and so on. 
I tried to use setY but it did not change the position of the Views or they disappeared completely. 
Is there a method to achieve this or is this a case for the `LayoutInflater`?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText et1;
    private ScrollView sv1;
    private ConstraintLayout cl1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et1 = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        sv1 = findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        cl1 = new ConstraintLayout(this);
        sv1.addView(cl1);
    }

    public void splitToChips(View v) {
        String content = et1.getText().toString();
        String[] products = content.split(";");

        TextView[] textViews = new TextView[products.length];

        for(int i = 0; i<products.length; i++) {
            textViews[i] = new TextView(this);
            cl1.addView(textViews[i]);
            textViews[i].setText(products[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `LinearLayout` with orientation `verticle` and add views in that layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add views to `LinearLayout`. In my case, I created a layout with a `Button`, `EditText`, and `LinearLayout` along with a vertical orientation inside of a `ScrollView`. Then, in the Java code, I simply added the following line to the loop:

```java
mLinearLayout.addView(textViews[i]);
```